# White Screen When posting in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter gives a white screen every time a form is posted:

Here is the controller logic [controllers/account.php]:

```
class Account extends CI_Controller
{
   public function create()
   {
    if($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE)){
        $params = $this->input->post();
        //add validation layer
        $accountOptions = array($params are used here)
        $this->load->model('account/account', 'account');
        $this->account->initialize($accountOptions);
        $this->account->save();
    }
            $header['title'] = "Create Free Account";
    $this->load->view('front_end/header', $header);
    $this->load->view('main_content');
    $content['account_form'] = $this->load->view('forms/account_form', NULL, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('account/create', $content);
    $footer['extraJs'] = "account";
    $this->load->view('front_end/footer', $footer);
        }
 }
```

Here is the Account Model logic [models/account/account.php]:

```
 class Account extends CI_Model 
 {

    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function initialize($options)
{
      //initialize
    }
 }
```

The view first loads fine then after filling the form and clicking submit, just white page.
I tried to add __construct to the controller and load account/account from there, the form does not even load. Any ideas?

**I just found the problem:** 
- The Model account has duplicated definition and the error_reporting was off!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have two classes with the same name `Account` (the controller and model). Check your server and/or Codeigniter log it should show up there.

I advise you to call your controller class Account and your model class M_Account. You can then rename the model to account whenever you load it, just like you did:

```
$this->load->model('account/m_account', 'account');
```

Comment: Thanks I noticed that and fixed it but still getting white screen and the logs said DEBUG - 2013-10-11 21:23:58 --> Controller Class Initialized   DEBUG - 2013-10-11 21:23:58 --> Model Class Initialized

Comment: Thanks for your time, I just found the problem.

Comment: So what was your problem? I'm sorry I was caught in something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
$this->load->model("account/account");
}
you load model,library and helper files in construct dont load to inside a function
```

Comment: I did that but the view/form does not render!

Comment: Thanks for your time, I just found the problem.